# ¿Como soluciono este error del cors en ionic3?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito solucionar ese error que aparece en consola de la app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- Puedes agregar un proxy en el archivo ionic.config.json de tu app Ionic para realizar pruebas.
En la documentación te dice como: [service-proxies](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuring.html#service-proxies).

2.- Tu servidor debe permitir peticiones javascript desde otros servidores para poder obtener información del servidor original. Mas información en Wikipedia: [CORS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercambio_de_recursos_de_origen_cruzado), Mozilla [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Esas son las 2 posibles soluciones a las restricciones que tienes para poder realizar tus peticiones.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción seria en tu script de php agregar:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

O si estas usando el framework slim según la documentación:

```
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});

$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://mysite')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
});
```

[Link a la documentación de slim](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/enable-cors.html)